# Importar dados via SSIS ou C#?

Tags: c#, sql, importação, ssis

Olá

Gostaria de saber uma forma mais profissional para realizar a importação de dados(TXT, CSV, XLSX e etc) tendo em vista que hoje fazemos isso via c# ou executando o comando de "Bulk Insert" do SQL.

Se devo usar SSIS ou alguma outra forma mais eficiente de importar esses dados e quais são as suas limitações

Atenciosamente.

Comment: Não existe essa dicotomia. Use o que resolve seu problema da melhor forma. Eu tenho a impressão que essa pergunta é baseada em opinião. Duvido que alguma resposta possa acrescentar algo útil aqui, pelo menos na forma atual. Se fosse algum caso concreto bem definido seria diferente.

Comment: Sim, você tem razão. De qualquer forma agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Depende meu caro !. Se você utiliza hoje bulk insert para carregar uma determinada tabela, não vejo problema algum. O [SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms141026.aspx) ou qualquer outra ferramenta de ETL como o [DataStage](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/pt/ibminfodata) é bem vinda quando a necessidade de transformação de dados (Por exemplo, se há a necessidade de Lookups, Alteração de Tipo de Dados, Integração entre Sistemas de origem distintos, entre outros.). Resumindo, podemos dizer: Utilize bulk insert para carregar uma tabela para repositórios e use SSIS para uma adaptação dos dados de forma mais elaborada.

Comment: Agradeço pelo esclarecimento sobre o assunto. Realmente é algo bem subjetivo porém consegui formar uma opinião sobre o método que adotamos.